# delete rows containing numeric values in strings from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with 2 columns, type and text
The text column contains string values.
How can I delete rows which contains some numeric values in the text column.
e.g:

```
`ABC 1.3.2`, `ABC12`, `2.2.3`, `ABC 12 1`
```

I have tried below, but get an error.  Any idea why this is giving error?

```
df.drop(df[bool(re.match('^(?=.*[0-9]$)', df['text'].str))].index)
```

Comment: What is the definition of numeric?

Comment: Any numbers present within a string..eg "ABCD12",  "ABC 1.3" , "ABC 1.3.3", "ABC 12"

Comment: As far as I know those are not numbers but digits. It is a question of definition though and in the end you are seeking an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case, I think it's better to use simple indexing rather than drop. For example:

```
>>> df
       text type
0       abc    b
1    abc123    a
2       cde    a
3  abc1.2.3    b
4     1.2.3    a
5       xyz    a
6    abc123    a
7      9999    a
8     5text    a
9      text    a


>>> df[~df.text.str.contains(r'[0-9]')]
   text type
0   abc    b
2   cde    a
5   xyz    a
9  text    a
```

That locates any rows with no numeric text

**To explain:**

```
df.text.str.contains(r'[0-9]')
```

returns a boolean series of where there are any digits:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
```

and you can use this with the `~` to index your dataframe wherever that returns false

Comment: Yes, this worked for me ! thanks. I just wanted to check if string contains any numeric characters like 1.2, 1 or 1.2.1 etc

Comment: This gives me the following error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`. My column `dtype` is `object`. I assume that means there are numbers and strings mixed in there (loaded with `read_csv`). How would one get around that?

Answer (score 3):

Data from jpp

```
s[s.str.isalpha()]
Out[261]: 
0    ABC
2    DEF
6    GHI
dtype: object
```

Comment: Looks good, but worth noting the implications, e.g. anything with `-` would be omitted; i.e. this mimics Python `str.isalpha`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you define numeric as `x.isdigit()` evaluating to `True`, you can use `any` with a generator expression and create a Boolean mask via `pd.Series.apply`:

```
s = pd.Series(['ABC', 'ABC 1.3.2', 'DEF', 'ABC12', '2.2.3', 'ABC 12 1', 'GHI'])

mask = s.apply(lambda x: not any(i.isdigit() for i in x))

print(s[mask])

0    ABC
2    DEF
6    GHI
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Well as I asked in the comment, what is your defintion of numeric. If we follow python's `isnumeric` with `split()` we get the following:

```
import pandas as pd
```

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['ABC', 'ABC 1.3.2', 'DEF', 'ABC12', '2.2.3', 'ABC 12 1', 'GHI']
})

m1 = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: not any(i.isnumeric() for i in x.split()))
m2 = df['col1'].str.isalpha()
m3 = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: not any(i.isdigit() for i in x))
m4 = ~df['col1'].str.contains(r'[0-9]')

print(df.assign(hasnonumeric=m1,isalhpa=m2, isdigit=m3, contains=m4))

# Opting for hasnonumeric
df = df[m1]
```

prints:

```
        col1  hasnonumeric  isalhpa  isdigit  contains
0        ABC          True     True     True      True
1  ABC 1.3.2          True    False    False     False
2        DEF          True     True     True      True
3      ABC12          True    False    False     False
4      2.2.3          True    False    False     False
5   ABC 12 1         False    False    False     False
6        GHI          True     True     True      True
```

Comment: out of the 4 options, the contains works for my case.  isalpha will return false if string contains special characters also like . , ' etc.  I only want to check if numeric characters (1 or 1.2 or 1.2.1 or 1.2.1.2 etc ) are present, then filter out the dataframe.

Comment: Ok great. That is however not my answer. ;)